# Advise on simplifying a PHP statement

Tags: php, joomla, coding-style

I am new to PHP and am coding a template file for a Joomla K2 item layout.

I have an 'extra field' `$extrafields[15]` configured which outputs as "Yes", "No" or "". `$extrafields[16]` is a text string.

I have this code, which works but would appriciate advice on how to simplify it, as I know it is probably a bit crude!

```
if (!empty($extrafields[15])): 
    if ($extrafields[15] == "Yes") {
        echo "<span class=sgl-bold>Sponsored by:&nbsp;</span>"; 
    }

    if ($extrafields[15] == "Yes"):
        if (!empty($extrafields[16])):
            echo $extrafields[16]; 
        endif;
        echo "<br>";
    endif;
endif;
```

Comment: `if (something is true) { if (it's still true) { ... } }` is pretty redundant...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be inclined to do something like this:

```
if(!empty($extrafields[15]) && !empty($extrafields[16])){ 
    if($extrafields[15] == "Yes"){
        echo "<span class=sgl-bold>Sponsored by:&nbsp;</span>"; 
        echo $extrafields[16]; 
        echo "<br>";
    } //endif not empty
} //endif yes
```

Comment: This produces different results for the same input data than the original code snippet.

Comment: @boundryfunctions I interpreted the intent as to print one line of text including $extrafield[16] when the IF conditions were met.

Comment: ...and you're probably right about that, just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Thanks @BigScar - I know this isn't 'quite' what my code was doing, it's actually fine for my use case, so thank you!  This is much tidier and what I was trying without knowing the correct syntax.

Comment: Just for others reference, I think there was a stray '}' and a missing endif;.  Well, I needed to add that to get it running anyway!

     `<?php 
            if(!empty($extrafields[15]) && !empty($extrafields[16])): 
                if($extrafields[15] == "Yes"){
                echo "<span class=sgl-bold>Sponsored by:&nbsp;</span>"; 
                echo $extrafields[16]; 
                echo "<br>";
                   } endif;
            ?>`

Comment: @NicNic I went back and did a little cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more concise with just some simple tweaks:

- Get rid of redundant if-clauses where possible,
- combine if-clause conditions where it makes sense, and
- don't use the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for your control structures to cut down noise.

The following snippet preserves the same functionality than your original attempt but is imho more understandable.

```
if (!empty($extrafields[15]) && 'Yes' === $extrafields[15]) {
    echo '<span class=sgl-bold>Sponsored by:&nbsp;</span>';
    if (!empty($extrafields[16])) {
        echo $extrafields[16];
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

That said, judging from the context, you probably want to go with the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30985738/1062304) BigScar posted here.

To make this snippet even more understandable, you should consider working on the data structure (though I assume that this is something forced upon you by Joomla):

- instead of a values in a numeric array like `$extrafields[16]` use speaking variable names like `$showSponsor` or the likes, and
- instead of the string values of `'Yes'`, 'No' and `''` use boolean values `true`, `false` and `null`.

Remember:

> [There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and *naming things*.](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)

Comment: Thanks @boundaryfunctions - yes I went with BigScar's version in the end but this is also helpful.  The data structure is that of the K2 CCK extension for Joomla and not my own.

For my own understanding can you explain what you mean by a 'more speaking data structure' though?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @NicNic, I edited my answer to hopefully make clear what I wanted to say.

Comment: Thanks @boundaryfunctions - that make perfect sense!  Shame the extension devs don't adopt that approach.  I guess it's a matter of consistency when user can create an unlimited number of 'extra' fields.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (@$extrafields[15] == "Yes") { 
    echo "<span class=sgl-bold>Sponsored by:&nbsp;</span>"; 
    echo @$extrafields[16]; 
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Using the [error suppression operator `@`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) should always be used cautiously – if used at all. Using it to avoid `isset()` and `empty()` shouldn't be encouraged because it will make debugging a nightmare.

Comment: I agree @ should not be used on higher level functions.   But in the case of hash maps, it really doesn't make the code any more difficult to debug than other languages which do not throw warnings if the key is not set (eg Java's HashMap).   Either the key exists or it does not.  The implementation of the hash in PHP is a bit silly IMO.   What makes the above code difficult to debug is it uses numeric keys rather than strings.  15 or 16 mean nothing.

Comment: I have no problem using `@` when it comes to simple output like this. It makes the code easy to read and gets the job done.

Comment: Thanks, this is the most concise (well, shortest) for sure.  I'm assuming @ stops the error from displaying right?  Why is there going to be an error in this example.  To the beginner, this is most logical example of them all!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  In PHP, the hash/array will print out a warning if you try to access a key/position that was not initialized.  For example `echo   $extrafields['non-existent-key']` will fill up the log with noise (if you are logging warnings).   There are a couple ways to avoid the warnings:  (1) You can check that the key is defined for example with `!empty()` or `isset)()`.  Or  (2) suppress the warning  and do the logic checks on the values, not the keys.  If the value is non-null, you know the key was set.